# anchor tags don't jump to new internal section id when on another section id

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, anchor

I have a website where I have two sections: `#about` and `#store`

Initially on page load, I can jump to a section but once I'm at a section I can't jump between each other. Seems like it only works when my URL is clean, nothing in its path but the apex domain.

I did my project in react/gatsby but this is more of an HTML issue. I have what I inspected below and further down I have my actual react code.
Here's my rendered anchor tags for it:

```
<a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
<a href="#store>STORE</a>
```

Here's my HTML sections:

```
<section id="about"> ... </section>
<section id="store"> ... </section>
```

Here's my nav bar component:

```
const ResponsiveNavBar = (props) => {
  //const { checkout } = useContext(StoreContext)
  return (
    <Header style={{ position: 'fixed', zIndex: 100, width: '100%', backgroundColor:'black', color:'white'}}>
      <Menu theme="dark" mode="horizontal" style={{backgroundColor:'black', color:'white'}}>
        { props.links.map(link => (
            <Menu.Item key={`nav-${link.title}`}>
              { link.badge ? <Badge count={props.count}><a href={link.link}>{link.title}</a></Badge> : <a href={link.link}>{link.title}</a> }
            </Menu.Item>
        )) }
      </Menu>
    </Header>
  )
}
```

Here's it being insantiated in my Layout:

```
let links = [
  {
  'title': 'ABOUT',
  'link': '#about'
},
{
  'title': 'SHOP',
  'link': '#store'
},
{
  'title': 'CART',
  'link': '/cart',
  'badge': true
}];
const MainLayout = ({ children }) => {
  const { store: { checkout: { lineItems } } } = useContext(StoreContext)
  return (
      <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
          query MainSiteTitleQuery {
            site {
              siteMetadata {
                title
              }
            }
          }
        `}
        render={data => (
          <Layout>
               <ResponsiveNavBar links ={ links } count={ lineItems.reduce((accum, prev) => ( accum + prev.quantity), 0) }/>
                <Content style={{ background:`url(${CrumpledBackground})` }}>
                    {children}
                  </Content>
            </Layout>
        )}
      />
  )
}
```

Here's my index page where it all comes together:

```
const IndexPage = () => (
  <>
    <SEO title="Home" keywords={[`edm`, `bass`, `raves`, `shop`, `merchandise`, `rave`, `warehouse`, `underground`]} />
    <MainLayout>
    <div className="content-wrapper">
      <Splash />
      <section id="about">
        <h2> Our Deal </h2>
        <p>Throwing parties is not all glamourous whether they are sweaty warehouse raves, bar shows, or large scale festivals. We take on all the sad work
        so we can provide the best experience for the DJs, listeners and the adventourus.
        For so many sad faces there many more smiles.</p>
      </section>
      <section id="store"><ProductGrid /></section>
      <section><button style={{ margin:'auto auto', display:'block' }} id="policy-button"><Link to="/policies">Returns & Private Policy</Link></button></section>
    </div>
    </MainLayout>
  </>
)
```

Comment: can you please give  us a link to your site, or create similar sandbox?

Comment: just deployed. my cart gets a 403 error, ignore for now. https://www.spinanddestroy.com/
I noticed it only jumps when your at the top of the page

Comment: works fine here. moving between them works

Comment: interesting maybe it's my caching. excuse the site debugging AWS stuff rn.

Comment: can I ask what browser you are in? I'm in Chrome. Doesn't seem to jump back to `#about` when I'm in `#store` and vice versa

Comment: Tested on Firefox